# Google Search - Business Attribute incorrect in image search results

Tags: seo, google-search, open-graph-protocol

Recently, Google image search started to display our business name as "Custom Mugs" as opposed to "Mugshots" which is the name of the business.

I have checked our Business Profile and everything there looks 100% correct. I have checked GMC and everything is correct there, but I believe the issue is happening on organic search results and therefore not related to GMC.

I then proceeded to inspect all the META tags and OpenGraph tags and again, everything looks 100% to me. I have even had Google re-index this page - but nothing changed.

To see an example of what I am trying to explain - Google Search: "graduation mugs"

Results:

[image]

The business attribute should read "Mugshots" and not "Custom Mugs".

And here are the Meta and OpenGraph tags used on that specific page:

[image]

Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please... anyone?

Comment: I am still experiencing the same issue... can anyone please try to offer some assistance.